# ¿Cómo establecer el color de tinte al RatingBar de Android en KitKat (pre lollipop)?

Tags: android, kitkat, design

estoy intentando que mi RatingBar se vea tintado en amarillo en android KitKat y no hay manera, siempre se ve azul.

> Intento con estilos propios

```
<style name="RatingBar.Yellow" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
</style>

...

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:theme="@style/RatingBar.Yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

> Intento con código

```
public static void setupRatingBar(RatingBar ratingBar, Context context, @ColorRes int colorRes) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(ratingBar.getIndeterminateDrawable());
        DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes));
        ratingBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(DrawableCompat.unwrap(wrapDrawable));
    } else {
        ratingBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}
```

> Intento con drawables

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yellow_star_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yellow_star_half" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_yellow_star_full" />
</layer-list>

...

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

Con este último logro mostrar el tinte amarillo, pero sólo aparece una estrella...

Answer (score 1):

#### Cambiar el color del RatingBar mediante un estilo:

Debe ser suficiente con agregar el style :

```
<style name="RatingBar.Yellow" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

y asignarlo a tu RatingBar, el problema debe ser que estas sobreescribiendo ese estilo con otro estilo que es,     `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`, eliminalo y prueba nuevamente:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"

    android:theme="@style/RatingBar.Yellow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

#### Cambiar el color del RatingBar programaticamente.

Si deseas cambiar el color programaticamente puedes realizarlo de esta forma usando [DrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html):

```
    RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

    Drawable progressDrawable = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
    if (progressDrawable != null) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(progressDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.yellow));
    }
```

Defines tu RatingBar:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />
```

En ambos casos obtendrias el cambio de color en las estrellas de tu [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He intentando quitar el estilo y poner mi tema y nada, y también hacerlo programaticamente como indicas y no es posible debido a que setTint está disponible a partir de la API 21.

Comment: En la primera opción olvidé agregar android:theme="@style/RatingBar.Yellow" con el tema debe funcionar. En cuanto  a la segunda opción precisamente por eso se usa DrawableCompat para que setTint() sea soportada en versiones anteriores y no tengas que estar validando ! =)